# VSCode: python linting not working despite plugin installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, lint

Here are my user settings:

```
{
   "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "editor.fontFamily": "Menlo",
    "workbench.iconTheme": "ayu",
    "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
    "workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": true,
    "workbench.settings.useSplitJSON": true,
    "debug.console.fontSize": 14,
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 15,
    "terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "underline",
    "terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking": true,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Predawn",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.rulers": [80,120],
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.linting.pep8Path": "pep8",
    "python.autoUpdateLanguageServer": false,
    "python.analysis.logLevel": "Warning"
}
```

I have also `pep8` installed:

```
➣ $ which pep8
/Users/pkaramol/Workspace/apiflask/venv/bin/pep8
(venv) Sun Jun 09-15:20:46 ~/Workspace/apiflask
```

However python linting is not working despite the relevant plugin named

> Python Extension for Visual Code

being installed.

Any ideas how to fix this?

**edit**: I have already selected my virtualenv in VSCode as the image below shows:

[image]

**edit**: Running `pep8` from VSCode terminal also runs as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Did you select your virtualenv in your VSCode project?
See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Yes I have, check my edit.

Comment: Consider re-installing VS-Code to check whether that works

Comment: If you run `pep8` from VSCode terminal, does it work? (The terminal should activate venv automatically)

Comment: Yes that also runs (check my second edit)

Comment: @pkaramol I have the same issue, what caused it for you?